# Looping through sub folders not working Unix

Tags: file, bash, unix, loops

I have a folder with multiple sub-folders and each sub-folder contains 10-15 files. I want to perform a certain operation only on the text files in these folders. The folders contain other types of files as well. For now, I am just trying to write a  simple `for` loop to access every file.

`for /r in *.txt; do "need to perform this on every file"; done`

This gives me an error ``` -bash: ``/R': not a valid identifier ```

Thanks for the help.

P.S I am using **cygwin** on Win 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your /r is the problem, that's not a valid identifier (as bash said, you need to drop the /). Also, this won't recurse into subdirectories. If your operation is simple, you can directly use the exec option of find. {} is a placeholder for the filename.

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Otherwise, try something like

```
for r in $( find . -name "*.txt" ) ; do
    echo $r
    #more actions...
done
```

Answer (score 2):

With bash:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*.txt; do ...
```

Comment: globstar requires Bash version 4.

Answer (score 1):

I would use "find" for your application case

Something like

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec doSomeThing {} \;
```

Comment: Is there no way to use `For` for this operation?

Comment: @dawnoflife : maybe you meant `for r in *.txt` but this will not recurse into subidrs (but you can use the value of r in the block of the for loop, using `"$r"`.  Both of these replies are the correct. the bash `for` does not understand '/r', which I think you picked up from the Windows shell. The bash `find` output processed by a `for` loop block, or with the `-exec doSomething` is much more powerful. Good luck.